# Django 1.4 TimeField migration fails on PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-south, django-1.4

I edited two fields on a model and changed them from `IntegerField`s to `TimeField`s:

```
class Model(models.Model):
    start_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
```

I'm using these two fields to save a naive time, which is not related to any geographical notion of time, and thus has no real 'time zone' (think something similar to race times). My local database is PostgreSQL.

However, the south migration generated from this change fails with the following error:

```
> main:0005_auto__chg_field_model_start_time__chg_field_model_end_time
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: ALTER TABLE "main_model" ALTER COLUMN "start_time" TYPE time, ALTER COLUMN "start_time" SET NOT NULL, ALTER COLUMN "start_time" DROP DEFAULT;

...

File ".../lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.py", line 52, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: column "start_time" cannot be cast to type time without time zone
```

The failed migration has this:

```
class Migration(SchemaMigration):

    def forwards(self, orm):

        # Changing field 'Model.start_time'
        db.alter_column('main_model', 'start_time', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.TimeField')())

        # Changing field 'Model.end_time'
        db.alter_column('main_model', 'end_time', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.TimeField')())
```

Any idea on how to make postgres happy about this migration?

P.S. I'm in the midst of development, so I really don't care about any data migrations. You may assume the DB is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you don't care about data, the simplest way would be to delete the column then add it again with type `Time`.

Either edit the current migration manually to do this. Or delete this migration, then comment the field and run `schemamigration --auto` then add the field and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up manually editing the migration script (Thanks @Maccesch) such that all `alter_column()` calls are replaced with `delete_column()` followed by an `add_column()`.

Note that this means that **no data migration is done** and any data existing before this migration will be deleted.

Code:

```
def forwards(self, orm):

    # NOTE: NO MIGRATION HERE!!
    # THIS _WILL_ CAUSE DATA LOSS

    # Changing field 'Model.start_time'
    db.delete_column('main_model', 'start_time')
    db.add_column('main_model', 'start_time', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.TimeField')())

    # Changing field 'Model.end_time'
    db.delete_column('main_model', 'end_time')
    db.add_column('main_model', 'end_time', self.gf('django.db.models.fields.TimeField')())
```

`backwards()` is similarly implemented.

Answer (score -1):

I too have come across this problem, the problem was with south's migrations when creating the new test database. Placing

```
SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
```

into your settings file fixed the issue for me.